# Insert in a new sheet all First January possible between to dates

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I'm looking to insert in a new Sheet all **First January** between two dates: We suppose in my first Sheet I Have in `A2`:`2024-01-01` and in `B2`:`2027-01-01`, what I'm looking is to have in Sheet 2 in column A all this values `A1`:`2024-01-01` // `A2`:`2025-01-01` // `A3`:`2026-01-01` // `A4`:`2027-01-01`!! Thanks for all!

If I have **Start Date** `2023-10-20` and **finish date** `2027-12-31` I want to have in a column this values `A1`:`2024-01-01` // `A2`:`2025-01-01` // `A3`:`2026-01-01` // `A4`:`2027-01-01`

Comment: What is your "to date"?

Comment: Sorry Two Dates!!

Answer (score 1):

This formula works on non O365 versions also in Sheet2 cell A1
This counts the start date year's also .

```
=DATE(ROW(INDIRECT(YEAR(Sheet1!A2)&":"&YEAR(Sheet1!B2))),1,1)
```

If not whole start year not required use this formula:

```
=IF(AND(MONTH(Sheet1!A2)=1,DAY(Sheet1!A2)=1),DATE(ROW(INDIRECT(YEAR(Sheet1!A2)&":"&YEAR(Sheet1!B2))),1,1),DATE(ROW(INDIRECT(YEAR(Sheet1!A2)+1&":"&YEAR(Sheet1!B2))),1,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=LET(x, SEQUENCE(B2+1-A2,,A2), FILTER(x,TEXT(x,"m/d")="1/1"))
```

---

When `Start Date` --> `10/20/2023` & `End Date` --> `12/31/2027`

[image]

---

For `Non-MS365` Users or those using `Older` versions may use the following, the following formula has an **advantage** over **volatile functions** viz. <kbd>OFFSET()</kbd> or <kbd>INDIRECT()</kbd>, which means the

> *Volatile functions recalculates whenever the excel workbook is open or*
> *whenever a calculation is triggered in the worksheet. This adds to the*
> *processing time and slows down your workbook. And as suggested by experts to be avoided as far as possible!*

---

[image]

---

```
=AGGREGATE(15,7,(A3+ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,$B$3+1-$A$3))-1)/
 (TEXT(A3+ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,$B$3+1-$A$3))-1,"m/d")="1/1"),{1;2;3;4})
```

---

Another option:

```
=LET(x, SEQUENCE(B3+1-A3,,A3), TOCOL(x/(TEXT(x,"d/m")="1/1"),2))
```

---

Comment: I try the same formula and the same values that you use, also in the same cell, but I have an error "That function isn't valid" and the FILTER is Highlight!

Comment: @user3147365 `FILTER()` isn't valid means it doesn't supports your version of `Excel`, hence you could use the second method which uses non volatile functions `AGGREGATE()` & `INDEX()` also may I know what is your excel version? Note that `FILTER()` function is available from `Excel 2019` onwards while for `SEQUENCE()` & `LET()` you would needs to have at least `Excel 2021`. And moreover for the specific reason to update answers with screenshot along with the formula bar to show that the formula is working solution.